# Rotate image along with touch to fix point in android

Tags: android, rotation, touch

I am trying to rotate image in image view coresponding with touch to fix pivote pint of image . i have seen many of example but i dont clear with all of it .somebody have idea ..how can do it this this ?

Comment: @ dhams I know this is an old question but I believe it is something to do with drawing straight onto a bitmap instead of using the onDraw method straight to canvas with setBounds(). I am having the same problem as my circle just resizes itself, did you ever get it fixed - if so could you share?

Comment: @Jonno yes i did ..i rotted the matrix and all done !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no code or details provided about where the bitmap is drawn i assume its at the center  of the screen. You can rotate the canvas on center point like this

```
double rotationAngleRadians = Math.atan2(currentX - centerX, centerY - currentY);
rotationAngleDegrees = (int) Math.toDegrees(rotationAngleRadians );

canvas.rotate(rotationAngleDegrees , centerX, centerY);
```